# Plotly line and bar graph in the same figure

Tags: plotly, bar-chart, linechart, plotly-python

I tried to plot a bar chart then and a line chart in the same figure with Plotly, but somehow only the later trace is showed in the plot, and I'm not sure what went wrong.

Below is the code with Bar only

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            x=test['count'],
            y=test['pur_grp'],
            orientation='h',name='count'))
```

And the resulting graph is ok so far

[image]

When I added the line element to the figure, only the line element is showed in the figure

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            x=test['count'],
            y=test['pur_grp'],
            orientation='h',name='count'))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = test['total'],
                         y = test['pur_grp'],
                       name = 'Total'))

fig.show()
```

and the resulting figure
[image]

I would also like to show the count value on the xaxis on the top since the "count" and "value" are of a different scale. After hours of searches but I'm still cannot find the suitable answers.

Thanks first for your advises.

Comment: I think the "count" trace is there, but due to the scale we do not see it (millions vs thousands). The legend includes the "count" trace as well.

Comment: You can add secondary axis to show "counts". [See](https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, there is no information on multiple plots. Furthermore, I didn't see many examples of using the x-axis as two axes, so I found an [example](https://community.plotly.com/t/can-plotly-support-2-x-axis-and-2-y-axis-in-one-graph/38303/6) in the plotly community and applied your code to it. I did not see any data presented, so I used sample data to create it. As for the description of the code, I intentionally repositioned the x-axis ticks to overlap. It is assumed to be the 2nd x-axis.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

grp = ['HAA','HAB','HAI','HAD','HAF','HAE','HAC','HAG','HAH','HAZ']
test = pd.DataFrame({'pur_grp': grp*10, 'count':np.random.randint(100,10000,100)})
test = test.groupby('pur_grp').sum().reset_index()
test['total'] = np.random.randint(10000000,100000000,10)

import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.update_layout(xaxis2= {'anchor': 'y', 'overlaying': 'x', 'side': 'top'})

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=test['count'],
    y=test['pur_grp'],
    orientation='h',
    name='count',
),secondary_y=False)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x = test['total'],
    y = test['pur_grp'],
    name = 'Total',
),secondary_y=False)

fig.data[1].update(xaxis='x2')

fig.show()
```

[image]